# how to set default transform, rotation setting, to 0,0,0 when adding mesh object

Tags: transforms

when adding a mesh object, default settings for rotation were at (0,0,0).
something changed, and now when I add a new object it's rotation settings are different. how do I correct this?
Thank you for the response. took a screen shot, saved as jpeg onto desk top, unsure of how to post here.

Comment: could you show a screenshot or share your file?

Comment: My guess is you've set a rotation (or align to view)  in add object operator panel (bottom of 3d tool panel or F6). Add object  Right click on the rotations and select reset all to defaults to re-zero.or uncheck align to view.

Comment: that resets for that object only. how to reset that to default for all new add object

Comment: @l.robbins the default for that is set in [preferences](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/editing.html).